# perform authorization check in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

In a blazor page, i want to (show/hide/set to read only/change style...etc) a text box if user has specific policy
so to achieve (show and hide) i did the following:

```
 <AuthorizeView Policy="CanReadNamePolicy">
     <Authorized Context="test">
        <inputText @Bind-Value="@Name"/>
     </Authorized>
 </AuthorizeView>
```

but the problem i have to repeat this for every policy, also what if same user is in multiple policies

So i thought of moving this logic to the code behind and use attributes to set the text box, but i couln't find a away to do the authorization check in the code behind

so i should have something like this

```
 if ((await Authorize("PolicyName")).Succeeded)
 {
    ReadOnlyAttr = "readonly";
 }
```

any idea if possible to perform the authorize check in code behind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a code snippet how you can do it:

> If the app is required to check authorization rules as part of procedural logic, use a cascaded parameter of type Task to obtain the user's ClaimsPrincipal. Task can be combined with other services, such as IAuthorizationService, to evaluate policies.

```
@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService

<button @onclick="@DoSomething">Do something important</button>

@code {
[CascadingParameter]
private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

private async Task DoSomething()
{
    var user = (await authenticationStateTask).User;

    if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(user, "CanReadNamePolicy"))
        .Succeeded)
    {
        // Perform an action only available to users satisfying the 
        // 'CanReadNamePolicy' policy.
    }
}
}
```

Note:

1. The InputText component must resides within an EditForm component.
2. It's `@bind-Value` not `@Bind-Value`
3. A policy can evaluate multiple requirements... You can still use the AuthorizeView to evaluate multiple requirements in a single policy.

Comment: thank you, If i evaluate multiple requirements with a policy, how can i change the attribute of my text box based on the requirements with a single <AuthorizeView>

Comment: Are you going to change a single text box or multiple ones ? Are you going to have one type of changes or only one ? You should be aware that if a policy has multiple requirements, all of which should succeed in order for the Authorization Service to return Succeeded == true. Perhaps its better you define multiple policies and multiple Authorization Handlers, and call  the AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync with the appropriate  policies and  Handlers, and then set the attribute(s) of the text box(es) depending on the evaluation of the policies.